# Scraping Youtube - sometimes program can't find html but I know it's there

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, youtube

I am trying to make a program that takes a youtube video link and a number n as inputs and crawls to the n'th "next video" from the starting video and returns a list of the links visited.

My function that finds the next video occasionally runs into this error:

```
... "in find_next_video 
    next_video_href = next_video_html['href']
    TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable".
```

I would say every 1 out of 10 times. More often than not, it successfully runs and returns the link of the next video. The step right before this one assigns next_video_html to the first  tag with class "content-link". So this error, as I understand it, means that assignment/search is failing.

Here is the function:

```
def find_next_video(start_video):
    # Get web page
    page = requests.get(start_video)

    # Parse HTML
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    #set html class that we will search by
    html_class = 'content-link'

    # Find first video with matching class
    next_video_html = soup.find('a', attrs={'class' : html_class})

    #Get href of next video and make link
    next_video_href = next_video_html['href']
    next_video_link = 'https://www.youtube.com' + next_video_href
```

I modified the function for debugging purposes so that it prints soup.prettify() (the html) to file when hasattr(next_video_html, 'href') evaluates to false (when the error will occur, as far as I can tell). This has shown me 2 things: the request function and parsing are working because it prints to file. Additionally, I always find the "content-link" class in the  tag where I expect it so I don't see why it can't find it.

I have also tried time.sleep() (up to 5 seconds) before making requests but that has had no impact. I am assuming it has something to do with adds or javascript or something else that I can't see that is going on.

[Here is a pastebin of the code w/ debugging.](https://pastebin.com/MDqXeQZ3) Note that the error code thrown by this because the function calling find_next_video() returns nothing when hasattr(next_video_html, 'href') evaluates to true.

[Here is the html saved on a page where the error occurs.](https://pastebin.com/CLGauLdE) Note the first  tag with class "content-link" is present.

Comment: beautifulsoup only extract static data. for JS embedded sites you need to use selenium because when you make the request there is might be page load and Html content is not available.

Comment: So it only is embedded with javascript occasionally? It works more often than not so it that seems unlikely. For now I am working around it by remaking the request and parsing it again.

Comment: if the page loaded, you get data in Html. otherwise, if page load takes time for request then data don't contain which is get from JS or ajax.